# Распаковать бэкап twrp

Tags: android, шифрование, резервное-копирование, архивация, recovery

У меня есть бэкап `/data` для `twrp`, но в нем сломано несколько неизвестных системных файлов. Единственное что мне нужно восстановить это `/data/data` и `/data/app`.

Возможно ли как-то распаковать этот бэкап и достать с него файлы?

Comment: Конечного можно. Там же на сколько я помню обычный архив tar

Comment: Попробуйте эту прогу https://www.7-zip.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему склеив несколько этих tar-gz архивов в hex редакторе